# Gridview: Change link button text base on value of cell in same row

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Below is gridview that I **want** it to be, **ID, Name** and **Status** are Label, **Action** is LinkButton

ID ------------- Name ------------- Status ------------- Action

1 -------------- Name1 ------------ Active ------------ Disable

2 -------------- Name2 ------------ In-active --------- Enable

3 -------------- Name3 ------------ Active ------------ Disable

How can I set the **LinkButton** Text to "**Disable**" or "**Enable**" depend on value (text) of **Status** (which is always either **Active** or **In-active**)?

My link button is as below, how can change the text 'Do you want to **proceed**' to 'Do you want to **Disable**' or 'Do you want to **Enable**' base on the logic above

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lbtAction" runat="server"
               CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ID")%>'
               OnClientClick="return confirm('Do you want to proceed?')"
               OnClick="DoAction"></asp:LinkButton>
```

Comment: Use `RowDataBound` and place your logic there.

Comment: Do it on RowDataBound event.

Comment: That's correct as suggested by @TimSchmelter; do it on `RowDataBound` event

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `RowDataBound` and place your logic there:

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        LinkButton lbtAction = (LinkButton) e.Row.FindControl("lbtAction");
        Label lblStatus = (Label) e.Row.FindControl("lblStatus");
        bool active = lblStatus.Text == "Active";
        lbtAction.Text = active ? "Disable" : "Enable";
        string onClientClick  = string.Format("return confirm('Do you want to {0}?')",
                                               active ? "Disable" : "Enable");
        lbtAction.OnClientClick = onClientClick;
    }
}
```

Comment: That solved my first problem, thank you! Can you help me with the second problem I just added to question?

Comment: @RonaldinhoState: i have edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Use Gridview `RowDataBound` event to achieve the same. Like below (not exact code but you can start with alike)

```
void RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
 if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        if(((Label)e.Row.FindControl("Status")).Text == "Active")
{
  //disable
}
else
{
//enable
}
}
}
```

Comment: He's using TemplateFields (since he mentioned labels and linkbuttons), then you can't use the `Cell.Text` because it's empty.

Comment: @TimSchmelter, correct. didn't observed that. Thanks for pointing that out.Answer edited. Was just trying to show the way to achieve the result. I am not much of asp.net guy :)